# Does the flutter admob package support mediation?

Tags: flutter, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, flutter-pub

Does the following package support mediation - [Admob_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter) - If yes, what are the steps that I should follow, if no, what packages out there support mediation or can make mediation easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin doesn't contains any ads library besides AdMob. You can manually integrate custom networks to app and library AdMob handle its. But if you want to request user access for personal data tracking (GDPR in EU), you should directly provide information about granted access to every additional ads network.